# 2-dimension TwoWay binding works as OneTime+OneWayToSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, controltemplate

I am trying to bind 2 dimensional list, to display it as a matrix of `CheckBox`es on screen. Binding seems to work one time (when window is displayed). It also updates source. But changes in source are not causing updating UI.

I've ViewModel with property like this (it doesn't have to be `propdp`, because list is not changed, only items are, right?):

```
public BindingList<BindingList<ViewModelPageBase>> Pages { get; private set; }

public ViewModelMainWindow()
{
    var page1 = new BindingList<ViewModelPageBase>();
    page1.Add(new ViewModelPageSettings() { IsSelected = true });
    page1.Add(new ViewModelPageProfile());
    ...
    var page2 = new BindingList<ViewModelPageBase>();
    page2.Add(new ViewModelPageAnalyse() { IsSelected = true });
    ...
    Pages = new BindingList<BindingList<ViewModelPageBase>>(new[] { page1, page2, ... });
}

public class ViewModelPageBase : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Caption { get; protected set; } // will be set in constructor of inherited page
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see it's a simple `List<List<T>>`. I tried `ObservableCollection` and `BindingList` both of them have said problem.

Then I have a custom control with `propdp` `Items` and following template

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Caption}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In window binding looks like this

```
<local:NavigatorMap Items="{Binding Pages}"/>
```

All said produce this result

[image]

It's correct when window appears, clicking checkboxes update `IsSelected` without problem, programmatically setting `IsSelected` doesn't update checkboxes.

What I did wrong? Why changes in `Pages` are not causing automatic update in the UI? It works more like combination of `Mode.OneTime` and `Mode.OneWayToSource`. I'd expect `Mode.TwoWay` (while I actually need `Mode.OneWay`). Specifying `TwoWay` explicitly in all places does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But changes in source are not causing updating UI.

This is because the properties of your ViewModel don't raise the `PropertyChanged` event. Make sure your class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and change the properties like this:

```
public class ViewModelPageBase : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _caption;
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return _caption; }
        protected set // will be set in constructor of inherited page
        {
            if (value != _caption)
            {
                _caption = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Caption");
            }
        }
    } 

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I overlooked that. Thanks! Double-thanks for such a quick answer.